# 3d CUDA kernel indexing for image filtering?

Tags: image-processing, cuda, filtering

I have an image feature matrix **A is n*m*31 matrix** padded for filtering and I have **B as a object filter k*l*31**. I want to obtain a output **matrix C is p*r*31 with the size of the image A without padding**. I try to write a CUDA code to run the filter B over A and get C.

I assume that each filtering operation over A with filter B occupied by one thread block so there will be k*l operation inside each thread block. And each shifted filtering operation will be accomplished at different thread block. For A(0,0) filtering will be on thread_block(0,0) and for A(0,1) will be on thread_block(1,0), so on. Also I have third dimension as 31. Each space at third dimension will be calculated in itself. Therefore with the correct 3d indexing over the matrices I might be able to have all the operation in very parallel form.

So the operation is

```
A n*m*31 X B k*l*31 = C p*r*31
```

How could I do kernel indexing for the operations efficiently?

Answer (score 10):

Here is some code I have written to do roughly what you describe.

It creates a 3D data set (called `cell`, but it would be comparable to your array `A`), populates it with random data, and then computes a resultant 3D output array (called `node`, but it would be comparable to your array `C`) based on the data in `A`.  The data size of `A` is larger than the size of `C` ("padded" as you call it) to allow for passing the function `B` over the boundary elements of `A`.  In my case the function B is simply finding the minimum within the 3D cubic volume of `A` that is associated with the size of B (what I call `WSIZE`, creating a 3D region `WSIZE` x `WSIZE` x `WSIZE`) and storing the result in `C`.

This particular code attempts to exploit data re-use by copying a certain region of the input A into shared memory for each block.  Each block computes multiple output points (i.e. it computes B a number of times to fill in a region of C) so as to exploit the data re-use opportunity of neighboring computations of B.

This might help to get you started.  You  would obviously have to replace B (my minimum-finding code) with whatever your desired B function is.  Also, you'd need to modify the B domain from a cubic one in my case to whatever sort of rectangular prism corresponds to your B dimensions.  This will also impact the shared memory operation, so you might want to dispense with shared memory for your first iteration just to get things functionally correct, then add in the shared memory optimization to see what benefit you can get.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
// these are just for timing measurments
#include <time.h>
// Computes minimum in a 3D volume, at each output point
// To compile it with nvcc execute: nvcc -O2 -o grid3d grid3d.cu
//define the window size (cubic volume) and the data set size
#define WSIZE 6
#define DATAXSIZE 100
#define DATAYSIZE 100
#define DATAZSIZE 20
//define the chunk sizes that each threadblock will work on
#define BLKXSIZE 8
#define BLKYSIZE 8
#define BLKZSIZE 8

// for cuda error checking
#define cudaCheckErrors(msg) \
    do { \
        cudaError_t __err = cudaGetLastError(); \
        if (__err != cudaSuccess) { \
            fprintf(stderr, "Fatal error: %s (%s at %s:%d)\n", \
                msg, cudaGetErrorString(__err), \
                __FILE__, __LINE__); \
            fprintf(stderr, "*** FAILED - ABORTING\n"); \
            return 1; \
        } \
    } while (0)
// device function to compute 3D volume minimum at each output point
__global__ void cmp_win(int knode[][DATAYSIZE][DATAXSIZE], const int kcell[][DATAYSIZE+(WSIZE-1)][DATAXSIZE+(WSIZE-1)])
{
    __shared__ int smem[(BLKZSIZE + (WSIZE-1))][(BLKYSIZE + (WSIZE-1))][(BLKXSIZE + (WSIZE-1))];
    int tempnode, i, j, k;
    int idx = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int idy = blockIdx.y*blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    int idz = blockIdx.z*blockDim.z + threadIdx.z;
    if ((idx < (DATAXSIZE+WSIZE-1)) && (idy < (DATAYSIZE+WSIZE-1)) && (idz < (DATAZSIZE+WSIZE-1))){
      smem[threadIdx.z][threadIdx.y][threadIdx.x]=kcell[idz][idy][idx];
      if ((threadIdx.z > (BLKZSIZE - WSIZE)) && (idz < DATAZSIZE))
        smem[threadIdx.z + (WSIZE-1)][threadIdx.y][threadIdx.x] = kcell[idz + (WSIZE-1)][idy][idx];
      if ((threadIdx.y > (BLKYSIZE - WSIZE)) && (idy < DATAYSIZE))
        smem[threadIdx.z][threadIdx.y + (WSIZE-1)][threadIdx.x] = kcell[idz][idy+(WSIZE-1)][idx];
      if ((threadIdx.x > (BLKXSIZE - WSIZE)) && (idx < DATAXSIZE))
        smem[threadIdx.z][threadIdx.y][threadIdx.x + (WSIZE-1)] = kcell[idz][idy][idx+(WSIZE-1)];
      if ((threadIdx.z > (BLKZSIZE - WSIZE)) && (threadIdx.y > (BLKYSIZE - WSIZE)) && (idz < DATAZSIZE) && (idy < DATAYSIZE))
        smem[threadIdx.z + (WSIZE-1)][threadIdx.y + (WSIZE-1)][threadIdx.x] = kcell[idz+(WSIZE-1)][idy+(WSIZE-1)][idx];
      if ((threadIdx.z > (BLKZSIZE - WSIZE)) && (threadIdx.x > (BLKXSIZE - WSIZE)) && (idz < DATAZSIZE) && (idx < DATAXSIZE))
        smem[threadIdx.z + (WSIZE-1)][threadIdx.y][threadIdx.x + (WSIZE-1)] = kcell[idz+(WSIZE-1)][idy][idx+(WSIZE-1)];
      if ((threadIdx.y > (BLKYSIZE - WSIZE)) && (threadIdx.x > (BLKXSIZE - WSIZE)) && (idy < DATAYSIZE) && (idx < DATAXSIZE))
        smem[threadIdx.z][threadIdx.y + (WSIZE-1)][threadIdx.x + (WSIZE-1)] = kcell[idz][idy+(WSIZE-1)][idx+(WSIZE-1)];
      if ((threadIdx.z > (BLKZSIZE - WSIZE)) && (threadIdx.y > (BLKYSIZE - WSIZE)) && (threadIdx.x > (BLKXSIZE - WSIZE)) && (idz < DATAZSIZE) && (idy < DATAYSIZE) && (idx < DATAXSIZE))
        smem[threadIdx.z+(WSIZE-1)][threadIdx.y+(WSIZE-1)][threadIdx.x+(WSIZE-1)] = kcell[idz+(WSIZE-1)][idy+(WSIZE-1)][idx+(WSIZE-1)];
      }
    __syncthreads();
    if ((idx < DATAXSIZE) && (idy < DATAYSIZE) && (idz < DATAZSIZE)){
      tempnode = knode[idz][idy][idx];
      for (i=0; i<WSIZE; i++)
        for (j=0; j<WSIZE; j++)
          for (k=0; k<WSIZE; k++)
          if (smem[threadIdx.z + i][threadIdx.y + j][threadIdx.x + k] < tempnode)
            tempnode = smem[threadIdx.z + i][threadIdx.y + j][threadIdx.x + k];
      knode[idz][idy][idx] = tempnode;
      }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    typedef int cRarray[DATAYSIZE+WSIZE-1][DATAXSIZE+WSIZE-1];
    typedef int nRarray[DATAYSIZE][DATAXSIZE];
    int i, j, k, u, v, w, temphnode;
    const dim3 blockSize(BLKXSIZE, BLKYSIZE, BLKZSIZE);
    const dim3 gridSize(((DATAXSIZE+BLKXSIZE-1)/BLKXSIZE), ((DATAYSIZE+BLKYSIZE-1)/BLKYSIZE), ((DATAZSIZE+BLKZSIZE-1)/BLKZSIZE));
// these are just for timing
    clock_t t0, t1, t2, t3;
    double t1sum=0.0f;
    double t2sum=0.0f;
    double t3sum=0.0f;
// overall data set sizes
    const int nx = DATAXSIZE;
    const int ny = DATAYSIZE;
    const int nz = DATAZSIZE;
// window (cubic minimization volume) dimensions
    const int wx = WSIZE;
    const int wy = WSIZE;
    const int wz = WSIZE;
// pointers for data set storage via malloc
    nRarray *hnode; // storage for result computed on host
    nRarray *node, *d_node;  // storage for result computed on device
    cRarray *cell, *d_cell;  // storage for input
// start timing
    t0 = clock();
// allocate storage for data set
    if ((cell = (cRarray *)malloc(((nx+(wx-1))*(ny+(wy-1))*(nz+(wz-1)))*sizeof(int))) == 0) {fprintf(stderr,"malloc Fail \n"); return 1;}
    if ((node = (nRarray *)malloc((nx*ny*nz)*sizeof(int))) == 0) {fprintf(stderr,"malloc Fail \n"); return 1; }
    if ((hnode = (nRarray *)malloc((nx*ny*nz)*sizeof(int))) == 0) {fprintf(stderr, "malloc Fail \n"); return 1; }
// synthesize data
    for(i=0; i<(nz+(wz-1)); i++)
      for(j=0; j<(ny+(wy-1)); j++)
        for (k=0; k<(nx+(wx-1)); k++){
          cell[i][j][k] = rand(); // unless we use a seed this will produce the same sequence all the time
          if ((i<nz) && (j<ny) && (k<nx)) {
            node[i][j][k]  = RAND_MAX;
            hnode[i][j][k] = RAND_MAX;
            }
          }
    t1 = clock();
    t1sum = ((double)(t1-t0))/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("Init took %3.2f seconds.  Begin compute\n", t1sum);
// allocate GPU device buffers
    cudaMalloc((void **) &d_cell, (((nx+(wx-1))*(ny+(wy-1))*(nz+(wz-1)))*sizeof(int)));
    cudaCheckErrors("Failed to allocate device buffer");
    cudaMalloc((void **) &d_node, ((nx*ny*nz)*sizeof(int)));
    cudaCheckErrors("Failed to allocate device buffer2");
// copy data to GPU
    cudaMemcpy(d_node, node, ((nx*ny*nz)*sizeof(int)), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaCheckErrors("CUDA memcpy failure");
    cudaMemcpy(d_cell, cell, (((nx+(wx-1))*(ny+(wy-1))*(nz+(wz-1)))*sizeof(int)), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaCheckErrors("CUDA memcpy2 failure");

    cmp_win<<<gridSize,blockSize>>>(d_node, d_cell);
    cudaCheckErrors("Kernel launch failure");
// copy output data back to host

    cudaMemcpy(node, d_node, ((nx*ny*nz)*sizeof(int)), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaCheckErrors("CUDA memcpy3 failure");
    t2 = clock();
    t2sum = ((double)(t2-t1))/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf(" Device compute took %3.2f seconds.  Beginning host compute.\n", t2sum);
// now compute the same result on the host
    for (u=0; u<nz; u++)
      for (v=0; v<ny; v++)
        for (w=0; w<nx; w++){
          temphnode = hnode[u][v][w];
          for (i=0; i<wz; i++)
            for (j=0; j<wy; j++)
              for (k=0; k<wx; k++)
                if (temphnode > cell[i+u][j+v][k+w]) temphnode = cell[i+u][j+v][k+w];
          hnode[u][v][w] = temphnode;
          }
    t3 = clock();
    t3sum = ((double)(t3-t2))/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf(" Host compute took %3.2f seconds.  Comparing results.\n", t3sum);
// and compare for accuracy
    for (i=0; i<nz; i++)
      for (j=0; j<ny; j++)
        for (k=0; k<nx; k++)
          if (hnode[i][j][k] != node[i][j][k]) {
            printf("Mismatch at x= %d, y= %d, z= %d  Host= %d, Device = %d\n", i, j, k, hnode[i][j][k], node[i][j][k]);
            return 1;
            }
    printf("Results match!\n");
    free(cell);
    free(node);
    cudaFree(d_cell);
    cudaCheckErrors("cudaFree fail");
    cudaFree(d_node);
    cudaCheckErrors("cudaFree fail");
    return 0;
}
```