# CUDA motivation for multi-dimensional kernel execution

Tags: image-processing, cuda, gpgpu

The division of work CUDA imposes into blocks is logical because it reflects the hardware (some amount of execution threads within a single execution unit, all in the same "block").

However, as I'm looking at implementation of image processing algorithms, it's not entirely clear why I should have 2D grids of blocks, each being a 2D grid of threads. Why won't 1D do? After all, the kernel call usually just sees the image as a linear 1D array of pixels anyway and has to compute its global index by multiplying the usual row * column + offset in column.

One guess I have is for spatial locality. We *usually* compute stuff for a pixel based on the pixels around it, so the 2D grid of threads makes sure that all adjacent pixels run within the same execution unit, thus can share local memory etc. Is this correct? Anything else I am missing? Maybe ease of programming somehow (although that's hard to believe since the code is computing a 1D offset anyway)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK the only reason for 2D / 3D grid is if it relates to the data. If you have 2D data (image...) or 3D data (particle system, etc.), you can make the code more readable by using appropriate block dimesions. Also, on older cards, there was 65535 limit for number of blocks in one dimension, so other dimensions were used to  get around it.

There should be no difference in performance whether you use 1D block of threads or 2D/3D block.

Comment: But code is not more readable since anyway the data passed into kernels is almost always 1D array and you need to recompute the offset from your coordinates.

Comment: @zlatanski: that really depends on the data, I wouldn't say it's "almost always 1D array" :)

Comment: What I mean is that all image processing samples you find have the data incoming as `uchar4*` - and then you compute your location within that array from the global index of the thread. The fact that the thread global index is 2D hardly helps making the code more readable

Comment: But yet if you look at all image processing tutorials and documents, they do use a 2D execution pattern. Hence back to my original question

Comment: @zlatanski: If they do so, it either seems more readable to them or it's just how they are used to do it. There is no performance difference whatsoever. It's really just about indexing...

Comment: I think the answer given is sensible.  Furthermore, its indisputable that if you want to launch more than 65535 threads on a cc 1.x/2.x device, you must use a 2D grid.  If someone likes the fact that they can readily create 2D indexing, and you find it to be "not more readable", it's not worth arguing about.    You're welcome to program in whatever fashion you wish.  It's not terribly difficult to pass a 2D or even a [3D array to CUDA C/C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14920931/3d-cuda-kernel-indexing-for-image-filtering/14926201#14926201) if you know the width at compile time.

Comment: @RobertCrovella: so this has nothing to do with the fact that 2D execution enables a square, rather than a line, to be examined by a block of threads that has access to common shared memory? If some heavy computation on an image is required (some sort of filtering, say), you usually care about neighbors in both X and Y directions. Being able to handle all of them in a single shared-memory-sharing block sounds like a motivation (as opposed to just a line). What are your thoughts on this?

Comment: Any necessary indexing can be synthesized.  Calling a group of threads a "line" vs. a "square" is arbitrary.  There is nothing magical about a 2D grid of threads as compared to a 1D grid of threads, regarding figuring out who the neighbors are.  Yes, I do think it might be conceptually easier to generate the indexing, and also make more readable code (which might be why you can find plenty of examples), but you were quick to shoot those down.  Anyway, this type of discussion strikes me as mostly opinion based.  I cannot come up with a sound example of 2D that cannot be realized with 1D.

Comment: Note that [the programming guide says](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#thread-hierarchy) " **For convenience**, `threadIdx` is a 3-component vector ..."

Comment: @RobertCrovella: thanks for the detailed explanation. I'm sure you guys understand it more than I do, so I need to spend some additional time thinking about this and writing code.